# Unable to connect Guidewire to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, guidewire

I am trying to config Guidewire to connect to a SQL Server database.

I am getting the following error:

```
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:14,957  INFO Configuration SecurityManager finished parsing C:\Tomcat9\webapps\pc\modules\configuration\config\security\security-config.xml
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:15,004  INFO Configuration Finished security config.
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:15,004  INFO Configuration Parsing C:\Tomcat9\webapps\pc\modules\configuration\config\config.xml for registry. No substitution is supported at that level.
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:15,035  INFO Server.RunLevel Starting database PolicyCenterDatabase on env null
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:15,145  INFO Server.Database Creating DBCP connection pool.
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:15,223  INFO Server.Database JDBC Driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, major version: 9, minor version: 2
04-Mar-2021 14:53:15.332 INFO [main] com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [gft-bike-insurance:europe-west2:guidewire] via SSL socket.
04-Mar-2021 14:53:15.348 INFO [main] com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.getInstance First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
04-Mar-2021 14:53:17.120 INFO [main] com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [gft-bike-insurance:europe-west2:guidewire] via SSL socket.
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:17,245  INFO Server.Database Time taken to verify database is up: 149 ms
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:17,341  INFO Server.Database Validating main database connections have all required properties
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:17,341  INFO Server.Database This database version is SUPPORTED. Supported database versions are (14.00.3008). Actual database version is (14.00.3257).
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:17,341 ERROR Server.Database Unsupported database version found: (Microsoft JDBC Driver 9.2 for SQL Server). Supported versions are (9.2.0.0).
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:17,356 ERROR Server.RunLevel An exception was thrown while starting a component. Setting runlevel to SHUTDOWN [Unable to validate database or JDBC driver version]
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:18,597  INFO Application.Rating.RateTableManagement Creating RTM row cache
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:18,613  INFO Application.Rating.RateTableManagement Cache timeout (in nanoseconds): 129600000000000
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:18,644  INFO Server.RunLevel Decreased runlevel to 'SHUTDOWN'
guidewire-docker                                               2021-03-04 14:53:18,644 ERROR Server.RunLevel ***** PolicyCenter unable to start *****
Caused by: gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: Unable to validate database or JDBC driver version
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.StandardDatabase.verifyDatabaseAndConnections(StandardDatabase.java:602) ~[pl-10.13.6.jar:?]
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.database.StandardDatabase.start(StandardDatabase.java:437) ~[pl-10.13.6.jar:?]
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.startDependency(InitTab.java:465) - (com.guidewire.pl.system.database.StandardDatabase@1aef7b9e) ~[pl-10.13.6.jar:?]
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.enterNoDaemons(InitTab.java:814) ~[pl-10.13.6.jar:?]
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.increaseRunLevelTo(InitTab.java:650) ~[pl-10.13.6.jar:?]
```

Database-config.xml file we put:

```
  <database
    name="PolicyCenterDatabase"
    dbtype="sqlserver">
    <dbcp-connection-pool
      jdbc-url="jdbc:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS:1433;DatabaseName=SampleDB;socketFactoryClass=com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory;socketFactoryConstructorArg=gft-bike-insurance:europe-west2:guidewire;User=sqlserver;Password=Guidewire@CambridgeLab2021"/>
    <upgrade
      defer-create-nonessential-indexes="false">
      <versiontriggers
        dbmsperfinfothreshold="600"/>
    </upgrade>
    <databasestatistics>
      <tablestatistics
        name="pc_jobuserroleassign">
        <histogramstatistics
          name="CreateTime"
          numbuckets="75"/>
      </tablestatistics>
    </databasestatistics>
  </database>
```

Can someone provide some help and suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Did you see the error?
ERROR Server.Database Unsupported database version found: (Microsoft JDBC Driver 9.2 for SQL Server). Supported versions are (9.2.0.0).

Comment: @CarlosDuque yes I saw the log we tried different kind of jdbc jars: mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11 ; mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre11 ; and mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11 all getting the same error message

Comment: Can you try logging in to SQL Management studio directly using your credentials, this will rule out that no problem with your credentials. If you are able to login successfully, then check if you have the mentioned Database created in your DB Server. Then replace the "IP_ADDRESS" variable in database config file to "localhost".

Comment: issue resolved, thanks all

Comment: @Luke Mao… Can you plz tells us how you solved this problem. This can help some facing with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The minor version of MS SQL server should match exactly with the specified release version, if you are not starting the server in dev mode. To start the server in dev mode use the below VM argument:

-Dgw.server.mode=dev

This will skip the SQL server version validation.